# How to split a file name by dot and get the 2 last portion

Tags: windows, batch-file, split

So the problem is that I will get filename such as:

```
"a.b.c.d.e.f.g"
```

and I need to get the 2 last portions. In this case,

```
"f.g"
```

and I don't know how many dots the string will have.

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 3):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "fname=a.b.c.d.e.f.g"

FOR %%a IN (%fname%) DO FOR %%b IN (%%~na) DO ECHO %%~xb%%~xa
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@echo off &SETLOCAL
SET "fname=a.b.c.d.e.f.g"
:loop
SET /a t+=1
SET "d="
FOR /f "tokens=%t% delims=." %%a IN ("%fname%") DO SET "d=%%a"
SET "f=%g%"&SET "g=%e%"&SET "e=%d%"
IF DEFINED d GOTO :loop
ECHO %f%.%g%
```

€: works for all delimiters, not only `.`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the parameter modifier `x` in %~xI` to access only the extension and then use it twice.

```
@echo off
set "fname=a.b.c.d.e.f.g"
for /F "delims=" %%A in ("%fname%") DO (
   set "ext2=%%~xA"
   for /F "delims=" %%A in ("%%~nA") DO set "ext1=%%~xA"
)
echo %ext1%%ext2%
```